# Careers home page needs work

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

I have mentioned this in the past: [Make company pages more visible on the careers site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195347/make-company-pages-more-visible-on-the-careers-site)

And it has become more annoying as we have decided to use careers to post for job listings.
The user interface is very hard to follow.  When I log into Careers I see this:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Screen shot:

[image]

**No** where on here do I see anything about company pages.  The "my profile" button is very misleading, it really isn't a profile - it is a resume.  So when I click "my profile" I was expecting to see something about our careers page, instead I see this:

[image]

Okay so really "my profile" is "my resume"...So that isn't where my company page info stuff is so I return back to the [home page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com)

Okay I thought I'll just click my name on the top right corner of the page, thinking clicking my name would yield the company page that I authored and the company page that [Monika](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/07/say-hi-to-nine-of-our-newest-newbies/) from stackexchange had set us up.

Nope instead I get this:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/2108

This is sort of fine as there is a button to the company page but at first I didn't even see that button.  Can we please get the widget type divs that stackoverflow profiles have when you click a profile.  That way I can see the company pages, job postings, etc right within my profile without further clicks?

But wait when I go to my profile page it shows as highlighted "my account" see screen shot:

[image]

So basically it shows "my account" but nothing else below, only after I click away from this page and reclick "my account" can I actually see my account.  See below here where the steps to actually see it

1. Click "my account" even though visually it is highlighted (in blue) as if it is the active page.  It really isn't active until after you click on it:

After I click on it I really get "my account":

[image]

Sorry for all the images, but I want to show you guys on careers that although the design is nice the UX is kind of missing a lot.  Can you guys please make this site a bit more intuitive?  It can be as simple as getting the company pages button as a link right away, or fixing it so that if you click your my account link you actually see the company pages.

Comment: I'm fine with it being called my profile, personally. It _isn't_ a resume, or a CV - it's a professional profile.

Comment: But on most sites a profile is simply attributes of your account on a site.

Comment: Sure, except on sites like LinkedIn, SO Careers, and some other job search or recruitment sites, where your profile is a Professional Profile which displays predominantly stuff you'd see on a resume or CV. Calling them profiles on sites seems to be the convention. The resume or CV would be a physical document or digital file you provide someone with.

Comment: @JonH Would you say your frustration here has more to do with the IA of the website? UI and IA are very different things. I feel your frustrations have more to do with HOW the website is architected than WHAT user interfaces are being used. Is that a correct assumption?

Answer (score 6):

Great points here.  We do have some pretty big design and UX projects coming up and everyone in the company is agreed that Company Pages are going to be a focal point not just on the homepage, but throughout the browsing experience.

The good news here is we just hired our first full time designer for Careers 2.0!

One thing I would point out.  Your use case is slightly unusual.  You're a user on both the Candidate and Employer sides of the site.  We default Careers to the candidate experience which is why you're profile is the CV/Professional Profile.  Most employers who are interested in creating and maintaining Company Pages always start from http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer.  Here you can go to "my company page" to update and edit.

Comment: Sounds exciting - I wouldn't really say it is slightly unusual, I can't imagine there arent any other developers out their that also play the role of supervisor - being that the supervisor is trying to find great talent.  Isn't that the point of the site is for managers to find great talent even if a manager may be a developer?