# Bought job listing, company page still does not show up with zip / city

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I posted this some time ago:

[Typing the ZIP code doesn't yield the company page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195998/typing-zip-code-doesnt-yield-company-page)

So we bought a job listing as shown here:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/40487/software-engineer-thyssenkrupp-system?a=Nnr5HqMw

When I search by city "Auburn Hills" or zip code 48326, the company page does not appear.
How do I link my company page to the job listing?  When you go into careers you can look at your company page and when you scroll to the section "Job Postings" you can only buy additional job postings.  No where on the interface is there a place to "Add" current job listings to my company page.

Can someone from careers please look at the interface and make this flow a bit better?

See this [Careers home page needs work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195988/careers-home-page-needs-work)
And this [Allow Stack Overflow profile rather than Careers profile to be shown for "Who you will work with"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195989/allow-stack-overflow-profile-rather-than-careers-profile-to-be-shown-for-who-yo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your company page and job listing are not linked is because they are owned by different users who are not part of the same company account. We don't support linking any job listing to any random company page (for obvious reasons).

In your case specifically, it looks like you are the owner of the company page, and you have already done the right thing by sending an invitation to the owner of the job listing to join your company account. All that needs to happen now is for this person to click the link inside the invitation email. Once that happens, the job listing and company pages will be automatically linked.

If necessary, you can resend the invitation email through your [Manage Users](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/accounts/users) page by clicking the "resend" link under "Pending Invitations". If you need any further assistance, please let us know.

Comment: Can you guys please link it for us some of our end users are not aware of this process.  Being that I am the owner of the company page.

Comment: @JonH we can manually add the owner of the job listing to your company account, however, in this case I'll need to bring this to the attention of one of our customer service people, as they may need to verify that this is the intention of the other party before taking this action. The simplest way to link their account is for the owner of the job listing to click the link in the invitation email. I would be more than happy to resend that email for you if you'd like. Otherwise, I will make sure someone gets back to you on Monday at the latest.

Comment: @JonH I've gone ahead and linked the accounts